# Inheritance using Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

```
class A<E>{

}
class B<E> extends A{

}

public class WildInDeclare<E>{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A<Integer> obj = new B<Integer>();
    }
}
```

When I compile the above program I got this error.

```
Note: WildInDeclare.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

After that I just replace `class B<E> extends A{` to `class B<E> extends A<E>{` **it works fine can you explain why it required to again write `A<E>` During inheritance with code Example Please.**

**The second Problem with Inheritance I faced.**
I update the above code with the follow code.

```
class A<E>{
    public A(E o){

    }
}
class B<E> extends A{
    public B(){
        super(E);
    }
}

public class WildInDeclare<E>{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A<Integer> obj = new B<Integer>();
    }
}
```

But it is not compiling why? I got the following error.

```
WildInDeclare.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                super(E);
                      ^
  symbol:   variable E
  location: class B<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class B
Note: WildInDeclare.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

How I can pass Parameter to Parent class?

Comment: What compiler error message do you get?

Comment: because you inherit from `A`, which has a generic in it´s class signature. If you leave it out `A` will be inherited as rawtype.(how should the compiler automaticly decide for you that the generic `E` for class `B` has to be used as the generic for `A` aswell)?

Comment: @OleV.V. question updated.

Comment: How does the compiler know that `A<E>` doesn't extend `B<String>`? The type parameter might be used for something quite different in the subclass.

Comment: for the second question, `super(E)`, what is `E`, it´s not a variable just a type, so the compiler tells you so (what should it pass?)

Comment: @KevinEsche how I can pass Integer or any other Reference that I used in `A<Integer> obj = new B<Integer>();` to parent constructor?

Comment: you didn´t pass anything, you just called the no parameter constructor. Again, what should it pass in this scenario? `0`, `1`, `2`? There is no value, you just defined that the generic type accepts `Integer`.

Comment: @LetDoit you can always pass `(E) null`.

Comment: @KevinEsche in parent constructor `public A(E o){` how to make E as Integer Type? what should I pass in super instead `super(E);`?

Comment: @KevinEsche why it also not working? super(5);

Answer (score 1):

> can you explain why it required to again write A

Because `A` is a generic class that takes one type parameter.  Ideally, you wouldn't be able to refer to the raw type `A`, you'd only be able to refer to `A<String>` or `A<Integer>` or `A<Map<K, List<O>>` etc.  Java lets you use the raw type for backwards compatibility, but in principle it should be compulsory to provide the parameter.

When you're saying that class `B` extends `A`, you still need to say what kind of `A` it extends; i.e. what the generic parameter is.  (This does **not** need to be the same as `B`'s generic parameter - you could for example define `B<E> extends A<String>` and that would be consistent.)

> the following code...is not compiling.  Why?

That code is just syntactically invalid.  You've defined `A`'s constructor to take an *object* of its generic parameter type.  So when you call `super()` from `B`'s constructor, you need to pass in such an object.  `E` is not an object - it's just the name for B's generic parameter.  So the compiler is right to say "cannot find symbol", there is nothing called `E` in scope.

If you wanted `B` to take an input parameter that it just passes to the superclass constructor, it would look something like this:

```
class B<E> extends A<E> {
    public B(E e) { // this parameter could be called anything, doesn't have to be e
        super(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to pass to parent's constructor without child constructor's parameter? `super(3);` also not works.

Comment: `super(3)` would work **if and only if** `3` is an instance of the generic parameter `E`.  But since this parameter has no bounds, it could be any type, and so the compiler correctly says this is not consistent.  (If you tried to construct a `B<String>`, which is thus a subclass of `A<String>`, you'd be trying to pass an `int` into a constructor that takes a `String`).  In general with unbounded parameters, you'll need to have the caller provide the constructor parameter for this reason.